# Determine why 100% of Mysql CPU is being used

Tags: amazon-rds, magento

I setup a database on an Amazon RDS server The server is a db.m4.xlarge which is 4 vCPU's and 16Gig RAM yes our Magento (1.9) based website keeps causing our database to spike to 00% CPU utilization. The site doesn't actually do any transactions and has a decent amount of traffic but we are talking like a few hundred people an hour . When I look in the Amazon RDS consol it also shows at times "72 connections" and yet 100% cpu utilization. I would think it would take more then 72 concurrent users on the site to cause the server database cpu to spike?

Is there any command to run to see which specific query or queries which may be causing the cpu to be at 100% ??

Well in our Amazon RDS consol the database shows 129 connections and 100%  in the "cpu" column . However when I connect to the database via mysql workbench and run the query SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST on the database it shows 2 entries for the database one with a command "sleep" and in the "time column it says 44 and

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|    db   |  Command  | Time   | State    | Info         
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| dbname  |  sleep    |  44    |          |                
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| dbname  |  Query    |  0     | starting | SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
```

Also we did not have this issue when the mysql was run on the server that the magento site is hosted on.

Comment: Run a `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` query and see if there are long-running queries. Magento's notoriously hard on databases - have you gone through the various performance tuning & caching steps that are typically recommended?

Comment: SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST , also you can split your server load creating a read replica only for a few hours to see any different behavior